# How can a maximal almost disjoint family exist?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Suppose $\mathcal A$ is a maximal almost disjoint family of infinite subsets of $\omega$. Let $A\in\mathcal A$. Let $B\subsetneq A$ infinite.  Then $B\notin \mathcal A$. By maximality there exists $C\in\mathcal A$ such that $|B\cap C|=\omega$. But then $|A\cap C|=\omega$, a contradiction.

Am I losing my mind or what?

Answer (score 2):

If $B$ is finite, then of course there are no such $C\in\cal A$; if $B$ is infinite, then $B\cap A=B$ and $|B|=\aleph_0$, and so $A$ is the $C$ you are looking for all along.

Similarly, by the way, if you take $B\supsetneq A$, again $A$ is the witness you're looking for.

Comment: ok I see . / / /